# How to override a onchange method in component?

Tags: blazor, components, blazor-server-side

Here is the component I use on other pages, I would like to override the OnValueChange method down below. So, on my child page or component, I have an OnValueChange method..do I need to setup as virtual and inherit from a new component..what is the easiest way to do this?

```
  <select id="ddlUsers" class="form-control" value="@Value" @onchange="OnValueChanged">
      @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value)) //rule out default value
      {
          <option selected disabled value="@string.Empty">--- Select User ---</option>
      }
      @foreach (var user in UserList!)
      {
          if (user != null)
          {
              <option value="@user.UserId">@user.UserName</option>
          }
      }
  </select>

@code {

    // Get list of users from db.

    private List<User>? UserList { get; set; }

    // Get the value of the selected value; used to pass to the child page or component.

    [Parameter]
    public string? Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    // Callback used to get or change value.

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is run when page is loaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Put a random delay in, get users

        await Task.Delay(400);

        // Get list of users

        UserList = await Context.Users
        .OrderBy(x => x.UserId)
        .ToListAsync();
    }

    // Store selected value of dropdown on value changed
    
    protected Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value!.ToString();
        return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);

    }

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is or isn't working?  What does "down below" mean here?

Comment: Your current code looks OK, except that you can (and should) remove the `Value = e.Value!.ToString();` line. Invoke the callback with `e.Value`.

Comment: When I try to run the component from the child page..it doesnt allow me to override the method give me...[2023-10-26T20:18:15.018Z] Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'FlexUserMaintenanceTool.Components.UserDropDownComponent' does not have a property matching the name 'onchange'.

Comment: That is not called 'override'. Your component  now has the property `ValueChanged` .

Answer (score 0):

You should use a virtual.

I've also taken a liberty and refactored your code to demonstrate some other changes you could implement.

1. I've switched to an `InputSelect` which includes type handling, and demonstrated that by assuming your `UserId` is in fact an int.
2. I've changed to using `IEnumerable` for collections to prevent over materializing.
3. I've changed some of your `nullable` handling.

Here's the refactored component:

```cs
<InputSelect TValue="int" id="ddlUsers" class="form-control" Value="Value" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged">
    @if (Value == 0) //rule out default value
    {
        <option selected disabled value="0">--- Select User ---</option>
    }

    @foreach (var user in UserList)
    {
        <option value="@user.UserId">@user.UserName</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<User> UserList { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<User>();

    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Fake an async. If this is a normal call no delay is required
        await Task.Delay(400);

        UserList = UserProvider.Users?.OrderBy(x => x.UserId) ?? Enumerable.Empty<User>();
    }

    protected virtual Task OnValueChanged(int value)
        => ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```

My User Code:

```cs
public record User
{
    public int UserId { get; init; }
    public string UserName { get; init; } = "Not Set";
}

public static class UserProvider
{
    public static IEnumerable<User>? Users => _users.AsEnumerable();

    private static List<User> _users = new()
        {
            new User { UserId = 1, UserName ="UK"},
            new User { UserId = 2, UserName ="France"},
            new User { UserId = 3, UserName ="Spain"},
        };
}
```